# MySQL and generating where claused

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I am doing some work with mysql and have a unique situation where the only solution that comes to me is to have every possible combination defined. I am wondering if there is an easier/better way of doing this.

This sql creates 5 categories of mpgs

```
SELECT
count(if(a.mpgcombined < 18, a.mpgcombined, NULL)) as under18,
count(if(a.mpgcombined >= 18 AND a.mpgcombined <= 23, a.mpgcombined, NULL)) as under24,
count(if(a.mpgcombined > 23 AND a.mpgcombined <= 28, a.mpgcombined, NULL)) as under29,
count(if(a.mpgcombined > 28 AND a.mpgcombined <= 35, a.mpgcombined, NULL)) as under36,
count(if(a.mpgcombined > 35, a.mpgcombined, NULL)) as over35
FROM styles a, jpgs b, models c, divisions d
WHERE d.divisionid = c.divisionid
AND a.styleid = b.styleid
AND c.modelid = a.modelid
AND a.mktclassid in ($this->mktclassids)
$this->where
AND a.sequence = 0;
```

These categories and there counts are then shown to the user as a bunch of checkboxes, but only if the count > 0.
The user can then select as many category ranges as they want.
The problem I came across is that if a user selects under18 and under24. a where clause like this will not work:

```
AND a.mpgcombined < 18 AND a.mpgcombined >= 18 AND a.mpgcombined <= 23
```

This will obviously:

```
AND a.mpgcombined <= 23
```

This stuff is dynamic so i do not know what the where conditions will be, so something like the first option allows me to not have to define sql for each possible scenario.
Is there anyway around not having to define the sql for every possible combination?
sql is not my strong point.

if your thinking that this query will make no sense with that where clause, do not worry this sql does not get called if the user selects mpg, it gets disabled, but the where clause gets applied to several other querys.

I need to know how to dynamically create this where clause for the given ranges, preferably without having to define the where clause for every possible situation, ie:

```
if(under18 && under24)
    $where = 'AND a.mpgcombined <= 23';
elseif (under29 && under18....)
```

You can get the picture of what im thinking.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are generating the `WHERE` clause wrap each condition and join them with an `OR`.

So your example becomes:

```
AND ((a.mpgcombined < 18 AND a.mpgcombined >= 18) OR (a.mpgcombined <= 23))
```

Comment: I like your answer but whats happen when under18 is chosen and then under29 is chosen and also over35. I need to be able to generate sql which might not be right but wont affect the overall query. Could you give me an example of when under18 is chosen, a middle option is chosen and then the over35 is chosen. To me it looks like i will still need all those if and elseif statements

Comment: You will need to have some if statements but you just append an `OR` clause after each first one.